# php download does not embed swf

Tags: php, http

I have a PHP file that sends SWF flash for client , the flash downloads but does not embed in the HTML .

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Edit :

a normal flash file (x.swf) is embeded into the browser normally , but the downloaded one using the php file (download.php?id=1) initiates a download and does not embed and is not corrupted , i think it is a headers problem , what is the MIME type for swf ??? can't find it !

Comment: Please elaborate and post some code. If the PHP file is outputting a SWF file, then there will be no HTML code present. If you're using a separate HTML file to embed the SWF, then you've probably forgotten to change the MIME type in PHP.

Comment: i have html code with link for the swf : `download.php?id=5` , this link downloads the swf (when u put it in the address bar) when i should just embed it . thats why the `<embed` and `<object` codes are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download headers were sent or MIME type is not recognized by the browser, maybe flash player is not installed. Posting code would explain everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try SWFObject, it is an easy-to-use and standards-friendly method to embed Flash content, which utilizes one small JavaScript file. http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/